# Search or filter conversations in Outlook 2007 that have more than x email items

Tags: microsoft-outlook, search, inbox

I'm having an email overflow (3k on my inbox) and am trying to get more efficient. I'm now organizing by conversation, which helps a lot. I wanted to make a search (or filter) on conversations that have at least 10 email items in order to start with those to clean my inbox. Any ideas how to do that?